# Symmetry settings have no effect (continues mirroring across Y)

Tags: mirror, axis, settings

Using Blender 3.0 in Sculpt mode. I have been (intentionally) mirroring across the Y-axis. However, now, I can't turn this off. In fact, no matter what I pick in the Symmetry settings, it continues to mirror across the Y axis.

Is there another setting somewhere to disable this - or is it a bug?

[image: Clay tool always mirrored]

[image: Symmetry sidebar settings]

Comment: do you have a Mirror modifier?

Comment: I'm not sure waht that is. I'm very, very new to Blender. How can I check?

Comment: Bring back the Properties panel tabs: https://zupimages.net/up/22/11/1thy.jpg then click on the Modifier tab and if you see a Mirror modifier, close it by clicking on the X

Comment: if you loose the symmetry you can still click on the Symmetrize button in the top right panel (down arrow on the left of XYZ buttons)

Comment: For others, I noticed when I turned it off this way - I lost much of the symmetry between the two sides (one side became very different from the other.) After disabling the mirror modifier, I "symmetrize"ed it (+y to -y) to get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring back the Properties panel tabs:

[image]

Then click on the *Modifier* tab and if you see a *Mirror* modifier, close it by clicking on the X button.